# jasper reports: consistent colors in charts

Tags: colors, charts, jasper-reports

I am facing this difficulty :

I want to indicate where my user is in a range of data in a chart, as well as where the average is.
That's not too difficult, that part I figured out already :)

However, if I have several charts in 1 report, my "user bar'" sometimes gets a different color, according whether it's below or above average.
This is very confusing for my users, because they can't think, let's say, "the yellow bar is always me".
The legend always has to be read, and that's not so user-friendly.

I'll illustrate the problem in an attachment.

I know how to have the same series color, but within this series, I want 1 particular color to always represent the value of the average, another to represent my user, etc.

Is this possible ?!
Thanks a lot in advance.

IMAGE CAN BE FOUND HERE : http://www.kava.be/cms_bldn/jaspercharts.jpg

EDIT: I'm working with the ChartCustomizer now :

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.yellow);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.green);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(3, Color.red);
```

Still, this handles the series in the order they arrive from the resultset.
What I'm looking for is how I can use the series expression (as entered in 'series expression' field in the categorie series dialogue), instead of fixed indexes like 0-3.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking whether the sequence of your series is same in both the chart's chart data, plus color series in chart properties is also or not.

If it is same than it should print same.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your resonse.
Both are indeed in the same order. I think he just allocates the first color in the series to the alue that comes first in the result set. And so the color of my client depends whether he's above or below average.

Question is : How can I assign a color to one of the chart series ?